# Including multiple variables in return statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an overview site with a filter function on top. The user can filter for location and department.

The code of the controller looks like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {


        $posts = Post::orderBy('titel')
            ->get();

        $standorts = Standort::get();

        $abteilungs = Abteilung::get();

        if ($request->filled('s')) {
            $query = strtolower($request->get('s'));
            $posts = $posts->filter(function ($post) use ($query) {
                if (Str::contains(strtolower($post->Titel), $query)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });

        }
        return view('posts.overview', ['posts' => $posts], ['standorts' => $standorts]);
    }
```

I need to provide the `$abteilungs = Abteilung::get();` aswell, but when I return it like this:

```
return view('posts.overview', ['posts' => $posts], ['standorts' => $standorts], ['abteilungs' => $abteilungs]);
```

The last part in the brackets is greyed out and I can't access it.

Is there a way to make this work or is the return view limited to two parameters?

Comment: Besides the point, but you should be doing a conditional query based on the request value, instead of pulling *everything* from the database and then filtering. E.g. `$posts = Post::orderBy('titel')->when($request->filled('s'), fn ($q) => $q->where('titel', 'like', '%'.$request->s.'%'))->get();`

Comment: The `when()` method executes the callback in second parameter only if the first parameter is true. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try in this way

```
$data = [
    'posts' => $posts, 
    'standorts' => $standorts, 
    'abteilungs' => $abteilungs,
];

return view('posts.overview')->with($data);
```

Or,

```
return view('post.overview',compact('posts','standorts','abteilungs'));
```

Comment: Hey @Md Sohanur Rahaman :) that's a nice way, looks way tidier than my current code. I just tried it and it worked like charm, thank you for taking your time and answering :)

Comment: That's My pleasure. Have a Good Day . Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass variable to view in several ways ..

**way 1:**

```
$variables = [
       'variable1'=>'something goes here',
       'variable2'=>'something goes here',
];
return view('view-file')->with($variables );
```

**Way 2:**

```
return view('view-file')->with(['variable1'=>'something goes here','variable2'=>'something goes here']);
```

**way 3:**

```
$variable1 = 'something goes here';
$variable2 = 'something goes here';

return view('view-file')->withVariabl1($variable1);
or
return view('view-file')->withVariabl2($variable2); 
or
return view('view-file')
->withVariable2($variable2)
->withVariable1($variable1);
```

**way 4**

```
$variable1 = 'something goes here';
$variable2 = 'something goes here';

return view('view-file',compact('variable1','variable2'));
```

Hope that,  everything is clear to you how to send variable to view in several ways. If you want to pass 1 or 2 variables and in future it doesn't need to increase variable then, **way 4** is recommended.
But from my view and real life experience I always recommend to use **way 1**

Comment: hey, thanks for the detailed answer!! :) Appreciate it, gives a good look on what's possible, since I am new to php & laravel that's very helpful. Thank you for your time & I wish you a nice day aswell :)

Comment: You can follow me at github and knock me any time for getting solution related to php .

Answer (score 1):

to pass more than one variable to your view you should do it like this

```
return view('posts.overview', ['posts' => $posts, 'standorts' => $standorts, 'abteilungs' => $abteilungs]);
```

Comment: Ah man how obvious could it be? Thanks a lot! I didn't even think about that way since I provided the second variable as seen at the top with its own brackets. Appreciate it! I will accept your answer as soon as its possible. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

in the view method, the second argument is for passing data to view, you can pass as many variables as you want
like below:

```
return view('post.review',['variableOne' => $variableOne,'variableTwo' => `$variableTwo,'variableThree' => $variableThree])`
```